# Compare 2 dates in mongo find method

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have mongo documents containing a last_active date and a created date. I would like to search for all documents where the **day** of last_active is not equal to the **day** of created, but I have no clue how to write the query.

In MySQL I would write it like that:

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%m-%d') != DATE_FORMAT(last_active, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For MongoDB 3.6 and newer:**

The **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)** operator allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language, thus you can leverage the use of **[`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)** operator to transform the date field:

```
db.test.find({ 
    "$expr": { 
        "$ne": [ 
             { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$created" } }, 
             { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$last_active" } }
        ] 
    } 
})
```

or using aggregation framework with **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "$expr": { 
            "$ne": [ 
                { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$created" } }, 
                { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$last_active" } }
            ] 
        } 
    } }
])
```

---

**For MongoDB 3.0+:**

You can also use the aggregation framework with the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline operator that allows you to process the logical condition with the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator and uses the special operations **[`$$KEEP`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** to "keep" the document where the logical condition is true or **[`$$PRUNE`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** to "remove" the document where the condition was false.

Consider running the following aggregate operation which demonstrates the above concept:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$ne": [ 
                        { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$created" } }, 
                        { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$last_active" } }
                    ] 
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

This operation is similar to having a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline that selects the fields in the collection and creates a new field that holds the result from the logical condition query and then a subsequent **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)**, except that **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** uses a single pipeline stage which is more efficient:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": { 
            "created": 1, 
            "last_active": 1,
            "sameDay": { 
                "$cond": [ 
                    { 
                        "$eq": [ 
                            {"$substr" : ["$last_active",0, 10]}, 
                            {"$substr" : ["$created",0, 10]}
                        ] 
                    }, true, false 
                ]
            } 
        } 
    },
    { "$match": { "sameDay": false } }
])
```

0r

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": { 
            "created": 1, 
            "last_active": 1,
            "sameDay": { 
                "$cond": [ 
                    { 
                        "$eq": [ 
                            { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$created" } }, 
                            { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$last_active" } }
                        ] 
                    }, true, false 
                ]
            } 
        } 
    },
    { "$match": { "sameDay": false } }
])
```

---

Another approach would be to use the **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** operator in your **`find()`** method but note that the query will be fairly slow since using **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** alone requires a table scan and the database executes the JavaScript expression or function for each document in the collection, so combine with indexed queries if you can as query performance also improves when you express it using the standard MongoDB operators (e.g., **`$gt`**, **`$in`**):

```
db.test.find({ 
   "$where": function() { 
       return this.created.getDate() !== this.last_active.getDate() 
   } 
});
```

or more compact:

```
db.test.find({ "$where": "this.created.getDate() !== this.last_active.getDate()" });
```

---

With the input:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "created" : ISODate("2014-12-19T06:01:17.171Z"),
    "last_active" : ISODate("2014-12-21T15:38:13.842Z")
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "created" : ISODate("2015-07-06T12:17:32.084Z"),
    "last_active" : ISODate("2015-07-06T18:07:08.145Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "created" : ISODate("2015-07-06T06:01:17.171Z"),
    "last_active" : ISODate("2015-07-07T10:04:30.921Z")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "created" : ISODate("2015-07-06T06:01:17.171Z"),
    "last_active" : ISODate("2015-07-06T09:47:44.186Z")
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "created" : ISODate("2013-12-19T06:01:17.171Z"),
    "last_active" : ISODate("2014-01-20T13:21:37.427Z")
}
```

The aggregation returns:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "created" : ISODate("2014-12-19T06:01:17.171Z"),
            "last_active" : ISODate("2014-12-21T15:38:13.842Z"),
            "sameDay" : false
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "created" : ISODate("2015-07-06T06:01:17.171Z"),
            "last_active" : ISODate("2015-07-07T10:04:30.921Z"),
            "sameDay" : false
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 5,
            "created" : ISODate("2013-12-19T06:01:17.171Z"),
            "last_active" : ISODate("2014-01-20T13:21:37.427Z"),
            "sameDay" : false
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this beauty. I like the approach with the $project pipline aggregation. Unfortunately this just works with UTC DateTimes, but I solved this by adding the missing time with the $add oeprator.

Comment: @makz No worries, actually the aggregation framework is the most recommended for such queries. Glad you found a workaround that deals with UTC datetime issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) in mongo aggregation to find out `created != last_active`  check following aggregation:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
{
    "$project": {
        "check": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": {
                    "$ne": [
                        "$created",
                        "$last_active"
                    ]
                },
                "then": 1,
                "else": 0
            }
        },
        "all": "$$ROOT"
    }
},
{
    "$match": {
        "check": 1
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "all": 1
    }
}
 ]).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be with $where http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/ 
Or you can use aggregate query. Something like this (improve to add fields that you need to retrieve):

```
db.dates.aggregate({$project: { created: 1, last_active: 1, are_diff: {$ne: ["$created", "$last_active"]}}}, {$match: {are_diff: true}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function within your query:

```
db.mycollection.find({
  $where: function() {
    return this.created.getDate() !== this.last_active.getDate();
  }
})
```